# The internet without computers - 1940s era

Tags: alternate-history, internet, radio

**Alternate 1900s**

Imagine that we are in an alternative Earth in the early to mid 1940s. There has been no World War 2. In this world there are analog computers used rarely in laboratories for specialised purposes. There are no digital computers whatsoever.

Radio technology (still valve based) is however all the rage. Telephones  work by having human operators who connect one caller to another by manually plugging them in at the exchange.

**Question**

If someone in this era invented "the internet", how closely (in terms of functionality and speed) could it approximate today's internet without digital computers?   You can assume that memory functions can be carried out by people with notepads. Or, you can invent a non-electronic alternative or banks of unreliable valves or electromechanical relays kept on permanently.

---

**Assumption**

Transistors can be considered impossible in this world.

Power consumption and inherent unreliability of components must be taken into account.

**Note**

Please ask for clarifications if necessary before answering. Thanks.

Comment: Clarification needed: define "advance".

Comment: You've got "the internet" in scare quotes here, so _lots_ of clarification needed.  What features of the Internet would you want to reproduce?

Comment: @Renan - I've edited to give measures. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @jdunlop - I've edited. Ideally I would want  everything to work as now except with the technology of the time (including memoery being people with notepads).

Comment: You have my upvote. I like the question and I want to give it a good answer, although the one I wish to give is fairly lengthy so I cannot type it now.

Comment: *"Telephones work by having human operators who connect one caller to another by manually plugging them in at the exchange":* automatic circuit-switching telephone exchanges were invented towards the end of the **19th** century, and rotary telephones started being installed in the first decade of the 20th. By 1920 all large cities in Europe and North America had automated telephone exchanges. But there were small villages which continued to have manual exchanges well into the days of the Internet, and direct international dialling did not become universal until the end of the 20th century.

Comment: I don't understand why "*analog computers used rarely in laboratories for specialised purposes*" create a demand for networking. Perhaps an additional assumption is needed.

Comment: Note that digital computers didn't start with transistors, but with vacuum tubes, aka valves, so you've already torpedoed yourself anyways.  Mechanical computers already had multiple ways to record/read data, so no need to involve people for working memory.  That aside, there's not much reason to just make a machine available - they were often purpose-built, and took a lot of resources to operate; depending on the kind of data you were looking for, the person on the other end could do it faster manually.

Comment: Did I miss something? most of the answers are, "what existing technologies in the first half of the 20th century could be considered the Internet of their day and age?" I thought the question was, "could you duplicate today's Internet in the first half of the 20th century without transistors?"

Comment: Relevant: [IP over Avian Carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) and [RFC 6214](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6214).

Comment: See [The Victorian Internet](https://amzn.to/329kQDg)

Comment: @jdunlop: If I'd have to guess, I'd speculate he wants to have instant messaging, social sharing (facebook/twitter/stackexchange), news, and an encyclopedia (wikipedia). Social sharing is probably the hardest of those

Comment: Sidenote: Internet is just connections. telegraphs handled that easy. What your question is really about is the world wide web and other services that use the Internet.

Comment: Digital computers didn't even start with valves, your world would be backwards compared to what actually existed in the 1940s era. Konrad Zuse built functioning mechanical _digital_ computers in the thirties for example. Analog computers were as impractical then as they are now.

Comment: If your world has aluminum, copper and silicon, someone will eventually invent the MOSFET transistor, and pretty soon after that your world's Commodore 64...

Comment: @AlexP I recall reading a statistic that by 1950, the volume of calls routed in the USA, if they had to be connected by hand, would have employed every single female American (call operators were invariably women in that era). So you simply cannot have today's ubiquity of telephones along with manual call-routing.

Comment: When I think about ppl building calculators in physics based games by directing a herd of sheeps I think nothing is impossible... (I won't say MineCraft... Damn I did it)

Comment: Do you consider search tools important?

Comment: When I was in college, instead of science fiction newsgroups, people sent around mimeographed fanzines through the mail. They were written by individuals, sent to a collator who put them together, then sent to the group. Forums with a long latency.

Comment: In the early days of the internet, sometimes transfers were sent extremely asynchronously. Hence the statement: Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of magtapes.

Comment: How do you define the Internet? The Internet is just computers highly efficiently sharing information. So without computers, what are you trying to share that can't be done via older methods? (telegraph, telephone, post, etc.) Is it the concept of having a server that you can log into from anywhere in the world to get your data?

Comment: The book "Ravage" (from Barjavel) discribe something similar. Actualy, the story is set in the future, but writen in 194x

Comment: Just a side note - naval and (later) anti aircraft artillery directors were in fact fairly sophisticated and widely used analogue computers prior to and during WW2.  Look up the Pre-war British Admiralty Fire Control Table. Analogue computers were a well understood if niche technology at the time.

Answer (score 33):

There were not less than four worldwide messaging systems in widespread use before the Internet. Your choice.

1. The worldwide postal system became available, if expensive, since the late 17th century. Before the establismnent of the [Universal Postal Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Postal_Union), correspondents in countries which didn't have direct postal agreements relied on specialized mail forwarders.
2. The worldwide telegraph network was slowly stitched together in the second half of the 19th century. The [first successful transatlantic cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatlantic_telegraph_cable) was laid in 1865, by the life-time efforts of [Cyrus Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_West_Field).
3. The worldwide telephone network was an interbellic development due mostly to transnational conglomerates such as the British Cable & Wireless, or the American International Telephone and Telegraph.
4. The worldwide [Telex network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex) rose to prominence in the years after WW2, and remained in continuous use until the Internet was able to take over its main function of transmitting authorized-ish written messages in almost real-time.

In addition, the shortwave [amateur radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) community, which boomed in the inter-war period, could function as the message carrier for non-commercial activity, similar to how the internet operated non-commercially in its formative years.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the telegraph network in particular. One might argue that the telegraph office was the internet cafe of the 19th & early 20th centuries

Comment: See "The Victorian Internet" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Victorian_Internet) which describes the telegraph in exactly these terms. Also for fun see "Going Postal" by Terry Pratchett, which has the Discworld version.

Comment: From 1876 : a couple getting married by telegraph.  What's more Internet than an LDR?https://www.newspapers.com/clip/31562878/married-by-telegraph/

Comment: Y0u might also mention amateur radio.  "Hams" have been talking to each other around the world since the invention of the radio.

Comment: @workerjoe: Yes they did, but they are not allowed to carry messages for others, except in emergencies.

Comment: @AlexP Hams can't relay third-party traffic *internationally* except in case of emergency, unless it's with a country that the US has an agreement on that subject with (which we do with most of the English-speaking world and most of the Americas).  But within the US, we can.  The biggest membership org. for hams is called the American Radio *Relay* League (ARRL) because it was originally set up on purpose to facilitate *relaying* messages around the country.

Comment: @workerjoe: Yes, we have radiorelays over here too. But that relaying is only for relaying messages between radioamateurs. As far as I know radioamateurs are not allowed to operate as communications providers for people who are not radioamateurs or for businesses. The radioamateur license is strictly for non-commercial purposes, is it not? (But things may be different in the USA -- I don't know.)

Comment: It has to be for non-commercial purposes, and you can't charge money for it, but the third parties (ultimate message creators or recipients) don't have to be radioamateurs.  As long as it's not-for-profit we can relay messages for non-hams.

Comment: @workerjoe: Added a reference to the non-commercial internet of the 1980s compared to the amateur radio network.

Answer (score 22):

## Someone invented the Internet more than a hundred years ago

It didn't work out because of the technical problems.  It was called the [Mundaneum](https://daily.jstor.org/internet-before-internet-paul-otlet/).  With powerful enough analog computers, digital counterparts of the like Charles Babbage had [already designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage), and monied backing neither Charles Babbage nor Paul Otlet ever had, you could potentially engineer and build custom analog computers that would run the Mundaneum.

The Mundaneum is simply a physical location that is an analogue to the ephemeral location we call the Internet. Its basic functions are essentially identical. With the Internet, I type "difference between dreadnought and parlour guitar", the request is sent into the workings of the search engine, whose automated algorithms return what (I desperately hope) are relevant documents, images, and videos that relate to my question. With the Mundaneum, I send a telegramme to their central receiving office who would then translate my request into the relevant catalogueing scheme, a research team would, using their own algorithms, research patents & makers & catalogues of musical instruments. They might write a short, well referenced report and telegraph that back to me. I don't know if visual data can be sent over telegraph systems, but they could easily mail a microphotograph of the pertinent visual data, along with their written report, which I would then have blown up to its original size.

While it is true that the Internet is a communications network, it is also more than just that. It is also true that the telegraph system through which the real world Mundaneum would have done its work is a communications network. The real world Mundaneum is simply the "cloud storage" part of the fictional world Internet. While the relays and wires and people sending the telegrammes are the "communications network" part of the fictional world Internet.

## What is the Internet, exactly?

What makes the Internet different than television?  Or radio?  Or the printing press, or the mail?  The Internet is:

1. A way to transmit information
2. That allows any node in the network to send messages to any other
3. In real time
4. And the contents of said messages can contain arbitrary data

Television is an audiovisual feed only; radio is audio only. Both are single-source many-receiver.  Telephones let anyone talk to anyone; but that specifically means *only talking*.  The mail isn't real time.

The Internet can do the job all these things did, and more.  That's why the Internet is replacing them all.  Already many "landline telephones" behind the scenes are transmitting calls over the internet.

## But there's another layer built on top

The internet technically existed in the late 90's.  It was nothing like what we have today.  But what we have today is nothing more than a few extras layered on top of "the internet":

1. The web is basically a collection of 'documents' your web browser knows how to display, containing 'links' it can automatically follow.
2. Organizations began using this technology as an interface to build and design ever more complex services.

You can think of any given website as a really big encyclopedia.  A URL is just a page number.  When you go to the site, you send the site's bank of servers a request.  The site's computers go find the document for you, and send it back.

Nowadays, of course, the documents are actually generated on the fly; when you go to hotels.com and search in the search box, their computers receive the request, decipher it, look up the relevant info in their databases, then craft a reply.  Google doesn't precompute search results for every search into an enormous encyclopedia; it has a queryable database, it runs your search, it spits out an answer.

## What Paul Otlet invented

Paul Otlet [invented Wikipedia](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/06/17/science/17mund.html) in 1910.  He called it the Mundaneum.  He couldn't actually build it, of course, but oh how he tried.  For decades, he tried.  But like [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage), his idea was simply so far ahead of its time he just couldn't make it happen.

He anticipated having a network of "electric telescopes" (computers) that could all talk to each other.  That's basically the Internet.  He anticipated using links to connect the documents into a giant interconnected web.

## What could be done without electronic computers

Charles Babbage already had a design for the Difference Engine.  His technology doesn't use transistors.  It isn't even electric.  We know that it works, if only you can build one, because in 1991 someone did.  The Computer History Museum in Mountain View [has another it uses for demonstrations](https://computerhistory.org/exhibits/babbage/).

Charles Babbage designed what is, for all intents and purposes, a machine computer.  He just was never able to get the money or resources to build such a ludicrously intricate piece of machinery.  But his [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine) was indeed a bona fide computer.

In your world, transistors simply don't work.  Analytical Engines will.  They'll never be anything like as powerful or as cheap to operate as electrical computers were even in the 80s.

## Hook Babbage and Otlet up with deep pockets

If Babbage had successfully been able to make the Analytical Engine a reality, then by the time Otlet comes into the picture, what we would call a modem might have existed: Imagine duct taping a telegraph to an Analytical Engine.

In which case, Otlet's grandiose vision can actually be realized.  The Mundaneum comes to be a thing.  In order to use it, you have to be at a place that has a connection to a telegraph line and an analytical engine.  But that's still a pretty big change; libraries and other place (like very up-scale hotels) will want one.

In turn, others will eventually start offering their own special services that you can '[tele]graph into'.  Said hotels will already have most of the equipment, so it's just a matter of hiring an Analytical Engineer to make the machine automatically respond to telegrams inquiring about reserving a room, or checking on the status of an existing reservation.  Banks will find having access to an information sharing network very lucrative, so they'll want in as well.

Comment: Fascinating. I had no idea. Analog computers aren't good at memory I believe. How would that work?

Comment: Please explain what the *Mundaneum* was and its limitations. I don't believe "the Internet" could have been built using what it was intended to be.

Comment: @JBH: The Mundaneum was a moderately large documentation center. There were *many* documentation centers in the world. Plus every large library in the world ran a documentation desk. (They still do.) No, I don't get this answer, but then, maybe the humor escapes me.

Comment: @AlexP -- The Mundaneum is simply a *physical location* that is an analogue to the *ephemeral location* we call the Internet. Its basic functions are essentially identical. With the Internet, I type "difference between dreadnought and parlour guitar", the request is sent into the workings of the search engine, whose automated algorithms return what (I desperately hope) are relevant documents, images, and videos that relate to my question. With the Mundaneum, I send a telegramme to their central receiving office who would then translate my request into the relevant catalogueing scheme...

Comment: If Ton has brought all of that and maybe a bit more into his/her answer, I wouldn't have downvoted it.

Comment: ...a research team would, using their own algorithms, research patents & makers & catalogues of musical instruments. They might write a short, well referenced report and telegraph that back to me. I don't know if visual data can be sent over telegraph systems, but they could easily mail a microphotograph of the pertinent visual data, along with their written report, which I would then have blown up to its original size.

Comment: @elemtilas: The Internet is a *communications network*. A documentation center is (very generously) analogous with an encyclopedia, except that it doesn't hold documents, but rather bibliographic entries for documents. The analog of the internet is the telegraph network which carries your message to the documentation center. (Basically, with a documentation center you place a query to the documentation desk, and they find for you a bibliography. It is then up to you to take the bibliography and find the actual books or papers.)

Comment: @JBH -- Ton Day can either copy my comments into their answer, or else write a similar description of what the Mundaneum is. Or I can do it.

Comment: @elemtilas Do it. SE promotes the idea of people improving other people's posts. We just don't do it here very often - and I'd really like to change that downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @AlexP in a now-deleted comment to this answer I pointed out that the *mundaneum* was more analogous to a web browser than the Internet. Still, it's an interesting piece of history that contributes to Chasly's post.

Comment: @AlexP - Hope I addressed your comment, by noting that the Internet / Mundaneum is not only a "communications network", but is also a "document centre". The communications network is used by both in order to access the document centre. I'd imagine that for the Mundaneum to reach its full potential, it would have, eventually, to serve as a document repository in addition to a mere indexing service. Especially in so far as a fantasy or fictional world context is concerned. Even with just the indexing service, the Mundaneum I'd still consider an analogue to the Internet.

Comment: "Someone invented the internet more than a hundred years ago" is a bold statement considering the Mundaneum has a tenuous connection to what the internet is. The internet that we know today has developed with the technological advancements that followed it and continued its development. The internet without digital data would become prohibitively expensive to even operate let alone to store physically. The Mundaneum fulfills only a fraction of what the internet can do today. Doesn't mean it isn't an interesting topic to consider, but I don't think its appropriate to call it the internet.

Comment: Hi, I did kind of gloss over a bit much - more than I thought - cause I had to get to work.  I'll elaborate more when I get a chance but basically - the internet is a standardized way to send messages, and most consider "the internet" synonymous with "the web", which is *very* similar to the Mundaneum.

Comment: Note that blowing up a "digital" microphotograph - meaning one that's encoded to be sent over telegraph lines, however the encoding is done - just doesn't work, since the information isn't there.  You just get large pixels.  You could of course use clever compression algorithms to get some reduction in size, but there are serious limits.  See for instance JPEG compression.

Comment: @TonDay: If "most" consider the internet to be the same thing as the web, then "most" are grossly mistaken. The internet is an inter-computer communications network. The web is a set of resources accessible of a specific set of protocols *over* the internet. There are many services running over the internet; for example, voice and video communications, electronic mail, and remote access.

Comment: I'm well aware.  I'm a software developer myself :) I just didn't have time to add those extra details.  I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: Okay, I left @elemtilas's hard work in what turned into the preamble to, uh, a giant wall of text.  But hopefully an illuminating wall of text!

Comment: An Analytical Engine would almost certainly have sufficient practical constraints to give you what you want.  You probably don't need to shunt Babbage into a different line of work.  Eliminating vacuum tubes is probably enough.  Think _less_ reliable and _more expensive_ technology than ENIAC at first, and even after decades spent refining them, they will still be fantastically expensive and finnicky devices.

Comment: What "analog computers" did Charles Babbage design? His only two well-known designs, the difference engine and the analytical engine, are *digital* computers. And severely limited digital computers -- fine mechanics is fine for what is does, but there is only so much it can do.

Comment: Whoops.  Fixed a dangling reference to Babbage designing 'analog computers'.  Thanks @AlexP

Answer (score 11):

**The Internet was imagined in the 1940s as Vannivar Bush's *"memex"***

Vannevar Bush was the head of the US Office of Scientific Research & Development during the war, and he wrote a famous essay called ["As We May Think"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_We_May_Think) that has been cited as a major inspiration for the developers of digital computers and the Internet.  The essay addresses the problem of the growing body of knowledge, so large that no one scientist can get a complete view of even his own field, and the inadequacy of library filing systems for helping people find relevant knowledge.  The machine he envisions called a [*memex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memex) makes use of analog technologies then emerging, to allow people to create links (he calls them "trails") between objects and to share the data as well as the links.  Although in our world those ideas led to a digital Internet, if you want to create a fictional analog Internet, the suggestions in his article should be adequate enough for you to depict them in your world.

Answer (score 7):

**It can be done: with a serious *[The Wild Wild West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Wild_West)* steampunk flavor**

Please note that "what if some critical branch of technology wasn't invented?" questions are always problematic because everything needed for that branch will still exist — so why wasn't it invented?

Anyway...

Given enough electricity and big enough buildings the entire Internet (but not its speed) can be implemented using telegraph wire and relays, which is all a switching transistor is.  A "bit" of memory is simply a specialized switching transistor. I can even create static memory by creating solenoid-driven cams that would "lock" a value into place until the solenoid (or its resetting solenoid) was activated. Thus, if the power went down, the "memory" would remain.

Do we have analogs of this behavior?

Oddly, we do: electromechanical pinball machines, where the "state" of the machine must be known and remembered during the process of play. The only thing missing is the state-locking mechanism that would let you turn the machine off, then back on, to continue the same game.  (Why do I know this? Because I own a 1973 Williams Triple Play machine, which is an awful lot of fun to play — and just as much fun to maintain.)

So, telegraph wires connect two cities — three wires, reference/ground, data from and data to (sounds like an old Modem, doesn't it? we want that third wire to allow simultaneous bidirectional transmission). On each end are the listening and sending apparatus of a telegraph. The difference is that they're connected to solenoids that allow an analogue computer to do something with the transmissions.

Memory is achieved with massive banks of what I'll call latch-lock relay assemblies that mimic [SR Flip Flops](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_1.html). One solenoid affects a SET, the other a RESET. The mechanical latch allows the memory to be maintained indefinitely (well, let's assume no earthquakes) even without electricity. They're activated using [diode AND gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_logic) ([1900's tech, right?](https://computerhistory.org/blog/who-invented-the-diode/)).<sup>1</sup> Thus, when a single column and a single row are line-active, only the one relay at the cross point is SET or RESET.

I did mention this would be painfully slow, right? I didn't? OK, it's going to be PAINFULLY SLOW.

The semblance of a digital computer can be created electromechanically with relays and diode logic.<sup>2</sup>

Frankly, the real problem is the human interface. So I would expect everything to be done using punch cards. (However, since [typewriters have been around since 1868](https://blog.oup.com/2018/06/nine-striking-facts-history-typewriter/), you could develop an output device that typed. I believe 1900s tech could come up with large rolls of paper, in effect, the [Telex machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex).)

**Conclusion:** Yes, the entire Internet could be conceptually implemented using 1900s technology. Even IP addressing could be done. It would be power hungry, slow as molasses, LOUD! REALLY REALLY LOUD! and would have an incredibly low MTBF<sup>3</sup> (mean time between failure). People would be constantly monitoring and replacing relays and other components.  But, it could be done.

Heck, you could even have a 1900s version of the Dark Web where people illegally tap those telegraph wires and hijack IP numbers to set up physical-location-unknown data processing nodes. (Although the idea of hauling all that equipment, including power generation, around in horse-drawn wagons is a bit daunting.)

*If you're interested, author Terry Pratchett implemented something like this called the "Clacks," based on semaphore tech. He even conceptualized a "ghost in the code." I'm a fan.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *If you insist on no semiconductor devices at all (you only said no transistors, so I'm cheating a bit), then the diode logic for memory could be replaced by a three-state voltage system where columns would transition between mid-volt and logic-high-volt and the rows would transition from mid-volt to logic-low-volt, the result is that one and only one relay could actually activate (having the correct potential across its terminals). Nothing else would because the voltage difference wouldn't be enough to fully energize any other solenoid. However, the power loss would, itself, power a small city.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Again, if you insist on no semconductors at all, I can implement full logic using only relays. It's just slower and more power intensive.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *As I've thought about it, I believe you could even set up a rudimentary form of [JTAG Boundary Scan](https://www.jtag.com/boundary-scan/) that could be used to lower the repair time.*</sub>

Comment: Regarding state locking, you really only need a single relay - though controlling it becomes more difficult. Use something easily magnetized; magnetize it to hold the relay in one position, then demagnetize to allow the relay to move back to resting position. The solenoids used in battery- and solar-powered irrigation valves operate this way. One example is https://opensprinkler.com/gardena-1251-using-osbee/ ; rayshobby.net also discusses it.

Comment: @user51614, that only works if you have power 100% of the time. The OP is expecting early 1900s technology. That's a very tall order.

Comment: `that only works if you have power 100% of the time` huh? These need power only when changing state. They use that power to magnetize or demagnetize something, and the magnetism or lack thereof maintains the state indefinitely without power. Solar-powered devices do not have power 100% of the time, and battery-powered devices would rapidly die if they had to keep a coil energized. If in doubt, look at the opensprinkler link - there are oscilloscope traces showing the power pulses.

Comment: Latching relays exist already. Some have two coils: one to latch on, one to latch off. Some have one coil and the direction of current flow makes them latch on or off (and when there's no current they don't move).

Comment: @user253751, [This is a traditional latching relay](https://www.morssmitt.com/product-categories/400202/latching-relays). I know you can do the same function by complicating the mechanics and using both the forward and reverse solenoid actions, but the power complications of the early 1900s are bad enough without having to figure out how to reverse the voltage potentials. That's why I ignored that path.

Answer (score 7):

The Internet does not require computers at all. Most of the protocols are simple enough to perform *by hand*, and even the protocols that *do* require some processing power are only designed that way *because we have computers*.

In a world without computers, those protocols could be designed differently, to only require calculations that an average operator can do in their head.

There is a (joke) April Fool's RFC that specifies IPv4-over-pigeon: [RFC 1149 – A Standard for the Transmission of IP Datagrams on Avian Carriers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1149). It *was* actually implemented and successfully tested by the Bergen Linux User Group in Bergen, Norway.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty closely, except for speed.

The core components of ‘the Internet’ are mostly conceptual. DNS lookups, communication protocols, common data exchange formats, resilient pathing algorithms: all of these are possible with analogue technology. A DNS lookup is just a complicated automated exchange, or can be run by humans. They existed without digital computers. Resilient pathing is basically a series of linked exchanges. All data transfer can be done with analogue audio signals and a known (standard) format. Output/input is a matter for the end user. If they use a pen drawing the waveform on paper or a person listening to the bios and transcribing: it’s the same as long as the protocols are being properly followed.

Where this falls over is speed and bandwidth. Even the best analogue exchanges take time to perform routing and need physical space and  have a limited number of possible transmission channels per wire (barring optical transmission technology like fibre-optics) to enable the connections. This limits the number of concurrent connections down any given path between two nodes. Any protocol that requires handshakes or error correction packets will be limited by the speed of both parties and every node in the communication pathway between the two. Without considerable research (which we’ve never had to do because digital computers are very good at this kind of thing), you will be severely limited by available connection lines.

Answer (score 4):

> There are no digital computers whatsoever.

Oh yes there are. You aren't the first person to make the mistake of thinking that "digital equals transistor", and no doubt you won't be the last. But all the others were flat wrong, you're flat wrong too, and your world ***will*** have digital computers, because digital computers were in widespread use across the world decades before the invention of the transistor. In historical fact, if this is supposed to be our 1940s then they didn't even have transistors then.

You've forgotten about relays, switches, motors, punch cards, punched tape, and all the ***many*** mechanical devices which are either on or off and embody digital state and processing. Relays are actually highly reliable to hundreds of thousands of operations. Motors and switches can be similarly reliable. In 1940 these mechanical digital processors were in the process of being superseded by valves, but mechanical and valve processing were both very much alive. The Enigma and Lorenz cyphers were broken by digital computers using these.

For your internet, I would even submit the Lorenz as being an example of what you could do in that direction. Before Lorenz, the operator typed messages into an Enigma machine, wrote down the encoded message, and sent it themselves using Morse. Another operator then reversed the process. With Lorenz though, the machines communicated with each other directly. The operator typed in the message, the machine automatically encrypted it, and the machine broadcast the encrypted message using the Telex product. On the receiving end, the other machine received the Telex, automatically decrypted it, and printed out the decrypted message. If you're reading this and thinking "mechanical SSH session", have a cookie. :)

I could give you dozens of examples of pre-transistor digital computers, but you can do the same if you JFGI. I don't mean to be overly harsh, but this is a bad question because you have even the most basic general knowledge of the history or technology. Not knowing is fine, of course, but I would expect some trivial googling before asking your question, and even a cursory search and a minimum of thought would reveal that the concept is fundamentally broken. Your question even explicitly says that valves exist, for goodness sake!

Then there's comms. I already mentioned this was a Telex. People had already invented digital communications. The phone network was already there. The phone network was still using operators, but the early automated exchanges were purely mechanical. And the phone system was interconnected around the world.

Frame challenge then. Your basic concept of "no digital computers at that time" is wrong. Your basic concept of "no digital communication at that time" is wrong. Your basic concept of "no global communications network" is wrong. All your prerequisites are there, exactly as we had. So you're asking us to answer a question which can simply be answered by "look at our world", and that has no place in worldbuilding.

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget that I used the tag *alternate-history*. I also used the phrase "alternative Earth" in the opening paragraph. This gives me a certain license to change things. For example in this world Charles Babbage was famous for  designing a widely-used drainage system and Alan Turing didn't have a war to make him interested in computers. He was a moderately successful lecturer in mathematics  who died of old age.

Comment: I just brought up Babbage's work in my elaboration on the Mundaneum answer.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Still doesn't work. There were digital computers well before Turing too. You would literally have to eliminate the concept of switches from humanity to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

**Pull messages vs. push messages.**

With the **http** protocol, the client computer queries a server, possibly half a globe away, for information. This query is relayed from a local server to that distant machine. The query might include information that is incorporated into the anwer.

The earlier [usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) system would push newsgroups from server to server. You dial up to the nearest one and look what they have. So imagine that the local *telegraph office* allows people to browse incoming "general interest" telegrams, and to send telegraphs "to whom it may concern." The telegraph office also forwards such messages to the next office down the line.

To that add [mailing lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailing_list). You send a telegram to subscribe, and then you get any telegrams by others to that address.

Comment: So magazines...

Answer (score 3):

> Radio technology (still valve based) is however all the rage. Telephones work by having human operators who connect one caller to another by manually plugging them in at the exchange.

We're looking at the wrong technology here. What we *should* be considering is the [telegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraphy#Electrical_telegraph) for storing/forwarding and retrieving messages.

We have most of the fundamentals in place.

I'd suspect something like a cross between [teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext), where fixed information was sent to terminals (as opposed to interactive terminals). We could have a constant stream of data, encoded on punched tape that's sent. Its probably possible to encode something like a destination, and have a fixed set of routes (maybe updated over telegraph).

Lets say our "routing" table is London -> Bombay -> Madras -> Singapore (practically there may be more hops).

Each site would have a routing table to the next hop to a location - London would know that if they send it to Bombay, Bombay would see its a message for singapore, look up the next table and know it needs to go to Madras and send it on.

As for mechanics - have a standard header, maybe a checksum and end (yes, its overhead) and punch from tape, with something like a code for the destination (SIN01 for singapore for example), write it to a punch card. Throw it into the appropriate bin for the next hop, punchcards are loaded into the machine that sends it to the next hop (so as long as the punchcard bin is full, we keep transmitting). Each punchcard essentially is a packet, and by having 'static' routes we might reduce some of the complexity of routing in a system with relatively few nodes.

This is essentially poor man's UDP over telegraph, and probably entirely doable mechanically. Since the lines are "fixed" and constantly transmitting, its a matter of picking up the message and getting the last mile sorted.

I'll leave ensuring delivery and such as an exercise to the reader, but might suggest it could be fitted into 'spare' space in a "packet"

<sub>as an aside Bombay is now Mumbai and Madras Chennai, but I've chosen to use the period appropriate names</sub>

Comment: This sounds good. I'll read it again when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pantelegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantelegraph) was the predecessor of the fax machine, invented in 1860s. It was followed by the Bildtelegraph in 1880.

It would be possible to Telex a request for information to a library, where they'd look up the information, and either Telex or Pantelegraph the answer back.

Answer (score 2):

**Memory and speed are the problems**

As others have mentioned,  you could technically build an 'internet' without technology at all.  Think Great Library of Alexandria, with some system to request documents and add documents to the library remotely.

Let's say there were millions of 'runners' whose job it was to be the transport layer of the network.  Want to add a document?  Give it to a runner, who takes it to the library and archives it.  Want to search for a document?  Give your search parameters to the runner, who goes to the library, carries out the laborious search,  hand-copies the results and returns them to you - in a few years maybe.   Photos?  Runnees are trained artists that can draw anything you aant drawn and add it to the library.

The problem is that for the internet to work, it has to do these things relatively fast, with high bandwidth, and it needs a LOT of storage.

We had an 'internet' of sorts in the 1980's with FidoNet, CompuServe, and other competing technologies.   But dial-up modems and the cost of memory even then limited its usefulness, as did its fractured nature.  If only a small portion of documents you are searching for are even available on the internet, its usefulness declines dramatically.

So if you want a *usable* internet, you need widespread adoption.  That means the amount of data that must be stored is massive.

To give an example of early non-solid state memory, look at the [Selectron Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selectron_tube).  This is probably the highest form of non-transister memory tech we had.  RCA's version could hold 256 bits of data,and cost (in today's money) about 5300 dollars.  If you wanted to store a typical MP3 (say, 3 minutes at 128kbps) in selectron tubes in 1948, You'd need about 3 megabytes, or roughly 45,000 Selectron tubes.  So your one-song internet page would require roughly $200 million dollars in storage, and those tubes, their power supplies and air conditioning would fill a building.

There was a 4kbit Selectron tube that never saw commercial use.  If we assumed those were available at the same cost, we could reduce the cost for your one-song storage to 10-20 million.

Before transistors and integrated circuits,  there was simply no way to store enough data in a way that could be accessed quickly enough to make a usable internet.

Then there's hard drives.  The first IBM hard drive in 1956 held 3.75 megabytes, and cost $34,000.  That's roughly the size required to hold a single MP3 file.  But of course, you'd need lots of solid state circuitry to operate one.

So, the bottom line is that, while you can build an internet out of anything,  to build one that has the features we have today (high bandwidth connections,  petabytes of data quickly retrievable) in a usable form that would provide real value to the masses, was utterly impossible without a whole range of technologies that were not developed until fairly recently.  Not just memory, but things like spread spectrum radio, fiber optics, etc.  Those in turn require modern electronics to make and operate them.

Comment: Thanks - very useful and informative.

Comment: MP3 files aren't the real thing to compare. If you want a pre-transistor internet serving up audio, you give everyone a dual connection - telegraph for data (with relays & vacuum tubes doing all the work) and telephone for audio. Hook up a jukebox and *poof*, instant music-on-demand.

Answer (score 1):

An internet could be made, but it would have to be about using animals like pigeons and dogs and even human beings for physical data transfer called a [sneakernet:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet) an "internet" where information is transferred with magnetic tape, floppy disks, optical discs, USB flash drives or external hard drives. [Magnetic tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_tape), that first item, was first discovered in 1928 as audio tape and [was used in World War II](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p07dg3wm). This alternative 1940s internet would be using animals and items to move cartridges of tapes between people and then use certain audio devices/mechanical computers to interpret this information from tapes. Even a system of capsule [pipelines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube) can be used to deliver tapes. Someone can even send data over the radio using certain methods and even use recording devices to 'write down' radio signals containing pertinent information onto audio tape. This system allows for radios to be used for wireless transfer of data in the form of audio recordings, these recordings can be written on magnetic tapes as 'information', and this information (music, Morse code for a message to a loved one, code for an equation, etc.) can be interpreted by computers/audio devices while be transported by people/animals.